# Youtube videos displaying not correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, video, youtube

I have got a new theme for my website and now experiencing some problems with Youtube videos on previously published articles.

I use WordPress platform, so usually when I want to a video to the article, I just paste video link to the editor. It used to work fine.

[As you in the screen shot, upper video has weird size, the one bellow is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxm5O.png)

I have tried to fix this issue by using this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
article iframe, article object, article embed {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can't tell what is happening, or maybe describe the behavior of the `iframe`

Comment: @Arqetech I managed to stretch video to the size of paragraph, but still I have a problem with the height of videos. If you check the formating on video 9 and 10, you will see what i mean: http://goo.gl/eeE6hk

Comment: try this `width: 100%; height: auto;` it should make the width span all the way in the container and the height auto will resize depending on the dimensions of the video.